# SQL Server: Using cross apply to find unique users

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to understand cross apply and also address a particular problem - with reference to below table find unique users of product 'a' who don't use 'b' which would be only 'u2' in the example below:

```
USE [tempdb] 
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'[test]') AND type IN (N'U')) 
BEGIN 
   DROP TABLE [test] 
END 
GO 

CREATE TABLE [test]( 
   [user] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
   [product] [varchar](8) NOT NULL, 
) ON [PRIMARY] 

INSERT [test] ([user], [product])  
VALUES ('u1', 'a') 
INSERT [test] ([user], [product])  
VALUES ('u1', 'b') 
INSERT [test] ([user], [product])  
VALUES ('u2', 'a') 
INSERT [test] ([user], [product])  
VALUES ('u3', 'b') 

select asuers.user
from (select distinct user from test where product = 'a') ausers
  cross apply (select distinct user from test) busers
```

with the following error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 31
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 32
Incorrect syntax near 'ausers'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
Incorrect syntax near 'busers'.
```

Thanks

Comment: Paul White has an awesome set of articles that explains CROSS APPLY. [Part 1](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69953/) and [Part 2](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69954/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to quote `user` with `[]`, otherwise it is treated as function call:

```
select asuers.[user]
from (select distinct [user] from test where product = 'a') ausers
  cross apply (select distinct [user] from test) busers
```